# GoLand No Tests Were Run

Tags: go, testing, jetbrains-ide, goland, go-generate

I have a method that I am testing, and everything seems fine. However, when I run the tests in GoLand, I can see in the output that the tests "PASS" but the test runner says "no tests were run".

Here's the sample method in `calculator.go`

```
package calculator

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Calculator struct {}

func New() Calculator {
    return Calculator{}
}


func (s *Calculator) AddTwoNumbers(num_one, num_two int) int {
    fmt.Printf("adding")
    return num_one + num_two
}
```

Here's the test in `calculator_test.go`:

```
package calculator

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func Test_Calculator_AddTwoNumbers(t *testing.T) {
    // Arrange
    calculator := New()

    // Act
    total := calculator.AddTwoNumbers(1,2)

    // Assert
    if total != 3 {
        msg := fmt.Sprintf("total should have been %d but instead was %d", 3, total)
        t.Error(msg)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 25):

Instead of `fmt.Printf(...` in `AddTwoNumbers` try either `fmt.Println(...` or `fmt.Printf("foo\n')`

The absence of the newline in the output of your `AddTwoNumbers` method is is causing the format of the test execution outputs to not have each test in a  new line. The test runner is not being able to interpret that a test was run. Adding that newline, keeps a clean output.

Comment: Thank you @creativityoverflow, it solved a long standing problem of mine.

Comment: That was exactly the problem for me, thanks mate!

Comment: Thank you, I wondered for a long time why one of my tests is run as a regular function

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using to check the verbose output of the test run.

```
go test -v
```

> -v
> Verbose output: log all tests as they are run. Also print all
> text from Log and Logf calls even if the test succeeds.

Comment: How to  configure that in Goland? Adding it to tool or program arguments doesn't seem to be the right place.